# How to check if sublists have same string elements regardless of order and place the sublist only once in another list

Tags: python, list, compare, sublist

I have a list **courses_per_semester** that looks like this:

```
[[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'], ['ENG102', 'CS230', 'MATH120', 'GER'], ['CS205', 'FREE'], ['GER'], ['CS106', 'CS215', 'CS107', 'ENG204'], ['GER', 'MATH220', 'CS300', 'CS206'], ['CS306', 'GER'], ['FREE'], ['CS312', 'CS450', 'GER', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['CS325', 'GER', 'CS322', 'MAJOR'], ['CS310', 'STAT205'], [''], ['CS443', 'CS412', 'CS421', 'GER'], ['CS444', 'FREE', 'FREE', ''], ['', '']], [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'], ['ENG102', 'CS230', 'MATH120', 'GER'], ['CS205', 'FREE'], ['GER'], ['CS106', 'CS215', 'CS107', 'ENG204'], ['GER', 'MATH220', 'CS300', 'CS206'], ['CS306', 'GER'], ['FREE'], ['CS312', 'CS450', 'GER', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['CS325', 'GER', 'CS322', 'MAJOR'], ['CS310', 'STAT205'], [''], ['CS443', 'CS412', 'CS421', 'GER'], ['CS444', 'FREE', 'FREE', ''], ['', '']], [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'], ['ENG102', 'CS230', 'MATH120', 'GER'], ['CS205', 'FREE'], ['GER'], ['CS106', 'CS215', 'CS107', 'ENG204'], ['GER', 'MATH220', 'CS300', 'CS206'], ['CS306', 'GER'], ['FREE'], ['CS312', 'CS450', 'GER', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['CS325', 'GER', 'CS322', 'MAJOR'], ['CS310', 'STAT205'], [''], ['CS443', 'CS412', 'CS421', 'GER'], ['CS444', 'FREE', 'FREE', ''], ['', '']], [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'], ['ENG102', 'CS230', 'MATH120', 'GER'], ['CS205', 'FREE'], ['GER'], ['CS106', 'CS215', 'CS107', 'ENG204'], ['GER', 'MATH220', 'CS300', 'CS206'], ['CS306', 'GER'], ['FREE'], ['CS312', 'CS450', 'GER', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['CS325', 'GER', 'CS322', 'MAJOR'], ['CS310', 'STAT205'], [''], ['CS443', 'CS412', 'CS421', 'GER'], ['CS444', 'FREE', 'FREE', ''], ['', '']], [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], ['ENG102', 'CS230', 'MATH120', 'GER'], ['CS205', 'FREE'], ['GER'], ['CS106', 'CS215', 'CS107', 'ENG204'], ['GER', 'MATH220', 'CS300', 'CS206'], ['CS306', 'GER'], ['FREE'], ['CS312', 'CS450', 'GER', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['CS325', 'GER', 'CS322', 'MAJOR'], ['CS310', 'STAT205'], [''], ['CS443', 'CS412', 'CS421', 'GER'], ['CS444', 'FREE', 'FREE', ''], ['', '']],...]
```

So **each list** is a course path till graduation that a student has taken and **each sublist** is the combination of courses each student has taken. I have 1500 students and **I want to create a new list with all the unique combinations of each sublist**. To be more precise I want to **check** if for example **courses_per_semester[0][0] is same with courses_per_semester[1][0],courses_per_semester[2][0] ,...,courses_per_semester[1500][0]**. Then do the same for second sublist of each list. Each time the code finds a unique sublist I want the combination to be put in a new list, for example the **first_sublist_combinations**. But **the most important** is that if one student has **this combination ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER']  and another student this one ['CS105', 'MATH101', 'GER','ENG101'] then I want the code to consider them the *same***. Not to place them as different. So **I do not care for the order**. So the first_sublist_combination will take ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'] **only** **once** and **not** ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'] **AND** ['CS105', 'MATH101', 'GER','ENG101']

I did not find a way to do so. I tried to do sets but sets only accept unique values and at some lists I have more than 1 empty items and it takes one the 1 which I cannot accept.

What I tried to do is the following:

```
for i in range(0,len(courses_per_semester)-1):
    for j in range(i,len(courses_per_semester[i])):
        if courses_per_semester[i][j]==courses_per_semester[i+1][j]:
             first_sublist_combinations.append(courses_per_semester[i][j])
```

but it does not work because probably I am not thinking about it in the correct way. 
I also transformed the list into a set

```
course_sets_per_semester = [[set(courses_per_semester) for courses_per_semester in sublist] for sublist in courses_per_semester]
```

but like this it only gives me string once even if it is twice in a sublist so I cannot compare them correctly even if I wanted to because the length of one sublist becomes smaller than another one when they are supposed to be same.

For example the first_sublist_combinations =[['CS105', 'MATH101', 'GER','ENG101'],['CS105','MATH101','GER','GER'],..]

Comment: Please share your research and code, and reformat your question to make it readable.

Comment: I shared now everything I thought about but I could not find a way to do so in order to provide the correct code. That's why I did not provide code from the beginning. @SimonN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `x` is your input list:

```py
res=list(map(lambda c: list(set(c)), zip(*map(lambda a: list(map(lambda b: tuple(sorted(b)), a)), x))))
```

which as per your example outputs:

```py
[[('CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101')], [('CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120')], [('CS205', 'FREE')], [('GER',)], [('CS106', 'CS107', 'CS215', 'ENG204')], [('CS206', 'CS300', 'GER', 'MATH220')], [('CS306', 'GER')], [('FREE',)], [('CS312', 'CS321', 'CS450', 'FREE', 'GER')], [('CS322', 'CS325', 'GER', 'MAJOR')], [('CS310', 'STAT205')], [('',)], [('CS412', 'CS421', 'CS443', 'GER')], [('', 'CS444', 'FREE', 'FREE')], [('', '')]]
```

Comment: I do not get the result. What I need is to place in a new list each time a unique combination(no order matters) of the first sublist of each list. Then in another new list the same for the second sublist of each list.

Comment: You mean like for each sublist you just want to filter out unique values ? so kind of go from `[arr1, arr2, arr3]` to `[unique(arr1), unique(arr2), unique(arr3)]` ?

Comment: for example the first sublist of one list is ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101']. The first sublist of another list might be ['CS105', 'GER', 'MATH101','ENG101'] and the first sublist of another list might be ['CS105', 'GER', 'GER','ENG101']. So I want to check the first sublists of each list and then put them in a new list called first_sublist_combinations = [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101'],['CS105', 'GER', 'GER','ENG101']] because the ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101'] and ['CS105', 'GER', 'MATH101','ENG101'] are the same items.

Comment: Try now - first sublist of the result refers to first items, second to second items, third to third etc...

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much @Grzegorz . Because I am new to python, the results I see are in parenthesis. Does this mean that they are arrayes/sublists or sets? I am sorry if my question is not that smart.

Comment: glad to hear that - round parenthesis refer to tuple - I had to make it that way, because otherwise getting unique values would be extremely hectic. Here you can read some more: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html Btw - since it worked, please mark my post as an answer to close off the question ;)